# Exception ocurred when executing command in hive

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

```
insert into table test values(1,'2231');
```

then errors shows in hive:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRApps.setEnvFromInputProperty(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)V

and I look up log in hive.log.it showed that

> 2021-03-17T17:25:30,851 ERROR [0ca47af1-d66d-4aa2-86cd-0a3a42cc53a6
> main] exec.TaskRunner: Error in executeTask
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRApps.setEnvFromInputProperty(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)V
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.setupContainerLaunchContextForAM(YARNRunner.java:537)
> ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-3.2.2.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.createApplicationSubmissionContext(YARNRunner.java:584)
> ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-3.2.2.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.submitJob(YARNRunner.java:326)
> ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-3.2.2.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:251)
> ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.1.3.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1570)
> ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.1.3.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1567)
> ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.1.3.jar:?]   at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
> org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
> ~[hadoop-common-3.2.2.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1567)
> ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.1.3.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:576)
> ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.1.3.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:571)
> ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.1.3.jar:?]   at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
> org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
> ~[hadoop-common-3.2.2.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:571)
> ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.1.3.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:562)
> ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.1.3.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:414)
> ~[hive-exec-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]  at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:151)
> ~[hive-exec-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]  at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:199)
> ~[hive-exec-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]  at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
> ~[hive-exec-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]  at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2183)
> ~[hive-exec-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]  at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1839)
> ~[hive-exec-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]  at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1526)
> ~[hive-exec-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]  at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237)
> ~[hive-exec-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]  at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1227)
> ~[hive-exec-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]  at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
> ~[hive-cli-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184)
> ~[hive-cli-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403)
> ~[hive-cli-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821)
> ~[hive-cli-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
> ~[hive-cli-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
> ~[hive-cli-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
> ~[hadoop-common-3.2.2.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
> ~[hadoop-common-3.2.2.jar:?] 2021-03-17T17:25:30,851 ERROR
> [0ca47af1-d66d-4aa2-86cd-0a3a42cc53a6 main] ql.Driver: FAILED:
> Execution Error, return code -101 from
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRApps.setEnvFromInputProperty(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)V
> 2021-03-17T17:25:30,851  INFO [0ca47af1-d66d-4aa2-86cd-0a3a42cc53a6
> main] ql.Driver: Completed executing
> command(queryId=root_20210317172524_9be7ad6e-0e7c-4951-826f-44daf163e8ba);
> Time taken: 5.586 seconds 2021-03-17T17:25:30,856  INFO
> [0ca47af1-d66d-4aa2-86cd-0a3a42cc53a6 main] conf.HiveConf: Using the
> default value passed in for log id:
> 0ca47af1-d66d-4aa2-86cd-0a3a42cc53a6 2021-03-17T17:25:30,856  INFO
> [0ca47af1-d66d-4aa2-86cd-0a3a42cc53a6 main] session.SessionState:
> Resetting thread name to  main

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `common` 3.2.2 lib:

```
hadoop-common-3.2.2.jar
```

> *`at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:32) ~[hadoop-common-3.2.2.jar:?]`*

---

The invoked method is implemented in the `3.2.2` version of the client common libraries. Also,  you are using an incorrect version of the core one:

```
hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.1.3.jar
```

> *`at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.(...) ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.1.3.jar:?]`*

---

Change the **MR client core** , **client-common**  and **client-app** for these versions:

[**`hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.2.2.jar`**](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/3.2.2)

[**`hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-3.2.2.jar`**](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common/3.2.2)

[**`hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-3.2.2.jar`**](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app/3.2.2)